# Beyond the normal distribution: what if a particular distribution can't be assumed

Tags: distributions, self-study

In a random sample of 150 community college students, the mean number of hours spent studying per week is 11.7 hours and the standard deviation is 4 hours.

Without assuming anything about the distribution of the number of hours community college students study per week, at least what percentage (approximately) of the students study between 5.3 and 18.1 hours per week?

Comment: That's 1.6 s.d.'s either side of the mean. If the given mean and sd were population figures rather than sample values, you could use inequalities like Chebyshev. The problem is Chebyshev doesn't take into account the impact of the sampling error in the parameter estimates. You may be able to bound the percentage from the sample values, but I can't see a neat way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say for your sample data that whatever percent it is lie between 5.3 and 18.1 hours/week.

You may be reaching for Chebyshev's inequality. If so, go for e.g. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) and don't return here. The "at least" suggests a problem with this flavour.

You can't say that otherwise without making some assumptions. You can calculate the probability that values lie between 5.3 and 18.1 hours/week, which is 1.6 SD either side of the mean, easily if you do assume a normal distribution.

Your question sounds like self-study, so I will stop there.